# how to do selection of array of ion-button in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: i want like this]i have to select the size of the product , so have to select one option at one time.
i am not getting what to do please help me

```
<div class="size-scroll" scrollX="true">
      <button ion-button class="btn-size size-span" *ngFor="let category of sizeArray ;let ind = index"
        (click)="btnActivate(category)"
        [class.selected]="category.isSelected === isSelected">{{category.title}}</button>
    </div>

btnActivate(ind) {
     console.log(ind.isSelected)
    this.isSelected = true;
  }

sizeArray = [
    {
      "title": "Btn1",
      "isSelected": "true"
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn2",
      "isSelected": "true"
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn3",
      "isSelected": "true"
    }
  ];

<div class="size-scroll" scrollX="true">
      <button ion-button class="btn-size size-span" *ngFor="let category of sizeArray ;let ind = index"
        (click)="btnActivate(category)"
        [class.selected]="category.isSelected === isSelected">{{category.title}}</button>
    </div>

btnActivate(ind) {
     console.log(ind.isSelected)
    this.isSelected = true;
  }

sizeArray = [
    {
      "title": "Btn1",
      "isSelected": "true"
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn2",
      "isSelected": "true"
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn3",
      "isSelected": "true"
    }
  ];
```

like flipkart we select the size option I want to create like that.
Can any one please help me.

So How to change change button color which user select dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<div class="size-scroll" scrollX="true">
  <button [ngClass]="{'selected':category.isSelected}"  class="btn-size size-span" *ngFor="let category of sizeArray;let i = index" (click)="btnActivate(i)">{{category.title}}</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.selected{
  background-color:red;
}
```

ts(component):

```
    btnActivate(ind) {
       for(let i=0;i<this.sizeArray.length;i++){
         this.sizeArray[i].isSelected = false;
       }
       this.sizeArray[ind].isSelected = true;
    }

sizeArray = [
    {
      "title": "Btn1",
      "isSelected": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn2",
      "isSelected": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Btn3",
      "isSelected": false
    }
  ];
```

Working demo :  [link](https://angular-7ybfwn.stackblitz.io)

Comment: what not working? userSelectedSize update when user click on any size and don't forgot to pass size in onSizeSelect method

Comment: i want to change the color of selection of button when clicks , I am able to pass the category when click of button but not able to change the color of the button, like above shown in image , i want to change the color of button when selected